# Session Variables are lost after redirect with header

Tags: php, session, header

i want to store some information in session variablle after login process. i can print the session variables in login post method succesfully. ie, i can fill the session variables.  if the user logined succesfully, i redirected to index but my session variables becomes empty.

My Login Post page :

```
    if($totalRows_Recordset1>0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_Session['Mail']=$un;
        $_Session['Password']=$p;

        header("location: Index.php"); 
        die();

    }
```

My Index page :

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_Session['Mail']; ?>
```

Comment: did you init session_start() on login page?

Comment: yes i did it on the login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION` needs to be capitalized, it's case sensitive. $_Session prints because you are declaring a local variable called $_Session. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: @user1889700 are you saying that it didn't work? or just expressing your disbelief that it was something silly like capitalization (It's hard to tell tone on text)

Answer (score 0):

Yea....capitalize $_SESSION
try this
$_SESSION['mail']=$un;

Then in index page...
echo $_SESSION['mail'];